# Dealing with Application Hangs / Deadlocks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, logging, deadlock

Question: Are there any ways of logging or determining where deadlocks occur in an application provided to a client (possibly by enabling some flags in the build process)?

Background: Usually when I am testing code and a deadlock occurs, I am running in Visual Studio, so I can hit debug all and find which thread is waiting and where, and I immediately know what the issue is. However, there is a certain issue which causes my application to freeze up very rarely (it is not detected in unit or integration tests). This happens on a clients machine where he is only running the executable binary. I'm interested in knowing if there are any features I can enable that can help report these issues, since it's hard to say exactly would could be the problem without a debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the client to create a minidump from TaskManager or Process Explorer.  See [this article](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/how-to-capture-a-minidump-let-me-count-the-ways) for more information.

Comment: Cool. I had never known about this before. It seems hopeful, but when the program freezes their whole computer freezes (as in the mouse won't even move), so they can't get to the TaskManager. Unless Ctrl+Alt+Delete still works, which I don't think we've tried.